# Queries with Nested Tables

Tags: sql

I found this code for Oracle:

```
select m.title, (select count(*) from table(m.actors))
from movies m;
```

Is there a SQL Server equivalent? I tried searching for nested tables based on column results but could not find any relative information.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested tables are not supported in `SQL Server`. You can use the Migration Assistant to convert nested tables in `Oracle` to tables in `SQL Server`. The Migration Assistant attempts to store the sub-tables in the form of `nvarchar` data type. If you want to convert them to standard tables in `SQL Server` database, you have to manually create tables for storing different attributes and link them with primary and foreign key relationships to the parent table.